# Convert huge JSON file to csv file

Tags: python, json, csv

I have a HUGE json file want to transfer to csv. I have searched a lot on  the internet, and I tried to write Python myself, but nothing works. I have been stuck here for one week. Would anyone please help me with it?
The json file format is:

```
{"Gid": "5999043768223797248", 
"rights": [{"grantorContext": "Freemium right added by Netlife", "sku": "CMO-STO-2-FREE", "rightId": "5340e29a6dc01000", "grantorId": "NETLIFE_B2C"}], 
"used_quota": "16.95", 
"creationtime": "2001-04-29 12:58:33", 
"devices": [{"last_connection": "2001-05-30 22:06:08", "os_version": "4.2.2", "auto_upload": "wifi", "last_upload": "2002-04-29 13:12:26", "device_name": "i-mobile i-STYLE 7.5", "platform": "unknow", "client_version": "2.0.0"}], 
"total_quota": 2.0, 
"Uid": ["666927729520"]}


{"Gid": "5999043740151320576", 
"rights": [{"grantorContext": "Freemium right added by Netlife", "sku": "CMO-STO-2-FREE", "rightId": "5340e29f72c05000", "grantorId": "NETLIFE_B2C"}, 
           {"grantorContext": null, "sku": "CMO-STO-25-M", "rightId": "53b5d2d8b0400000", "grantorId": "DTN"}], 
"used_quota": "480.85", 
"creationtime": "2001-04-29 12:58:38", 
"devices": [{"last_connection": "2001-08-02 03:46:05", "os_version": "8.4", "auto_upload": "wifi", "last_upload": "2015-08-02 03:46:05", "device_name": "Nokia", "platform": "unknow", "client_version": "1.0.0"}], 
"total_quota": 27.0, 
"Uid": ["465949097714"]}


{"Gid": "5999043675907166208", 
"rights": [{"grantorContext": null, "sku": "CMO-STO-25-M", "rightId": "53b5d2e161000000", "grantorId": "DTN"}, 
           {"grantorContext": "Freemium right added by Netlife", "sku": "CMO-STO-2-FREE", "rightId": "5340e29b42805000", "grantorId": "NETLIFE_B2C"}], 
"used_quota": "8.26", 
"creationtime": "2001-04-29 12:58:35", 
"devices": [{"last_connection": "2001-04-29 13:08:24", "os_version": "4.2.2", "auto_upload": "wifi", "last_upload": "2002-04-29 13:03:25", "device_name": "Nokia V797", "platform": "unknow", "client_version": "2.0.0"}], 
"total_quota": 27.0, 
"Uid": ["666994575443"]}
```

Comment: If nothing works despite you trying everything then we are all doomed and world is about come to an end. But then I doubt it, so please post some of your attempts and explain what happens, and what is supposed to.

Comment: If you started with a small JSON file and wrote a program to convert that to CSV, that would be a step towards a solution to your HUGE problem?

Comment: How big is the JSON file?

Comment: searching for 'python convert json csv' (without the '' quotes), or 'python read huge json' both produce lots of answers, including several on stackoverflow.

Comment: Thank you for all your answers, guys. The file is 350M by today, and it grows fast. I am still struggling, any help would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar file myself!

It's not a valid JSON file. It's a set of JSON files concatenanted into one. From the python json.dumps documentation

> *Unlike pickle and marshal, JSON is not a framed protocol, so trying to*
>   *serialize multiple objects with repeated calls to dump() using the*
>   *same fp will result in an invalid JSON file*

Which means that even if it would all fit in memory at once, you can't use json.load to read this file unless you edit a "[" prior to the first line and a "]" at the end and commas between each element (ie at the blank line between "}" and "{"

You can fight with the python json module and get it to do what I think you want, to read sequentially each group of seven elements as a python dict with keys "Gid" "rights" etc.

You have to use the raw_decode method of the JSONDecoder class, which will stop at the closing "}" and return the index into the string it is scanning so that you can chop off what it's just processed.

So read a comfortably large chunk of the huge file, and inside an exception handler try to raw_decode an element. If it succeeds, save the decoded result, delete the part that's been successfully decoded, and repeat. If you get an exception, read another chunk from the file and append to the string you are decoding and repeat. If you still get an exception, the JSON element you are at is corrupt (or longer than your chunk size, or you've failed to correctly process end of file).

It's far easier to code if your file is less than a few tens (hundreds? ) of Mbytes. Then, just read the entire thing into a string and start chomping JSON elements off the front of it until there's nothing but whitespace left or until you hit a decoder error.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the brute-force way, for when the file is small enough to treat as a single string without running out of memory

```
import json
import re

multijsons = open('file.json','r').read()

sep = re.compile( r'\}\s*\{' )
jsonlist = '[' + re.sub( sep, '}, {', multijsons ) + ']'

load =  json.loads( jsonlist)

# quick debug:
for item in load:
    print item
    print '\n---\n'
```

this is what I used because my file was not so very huge. Thought about coding the above but didn't need it and it looked as if it would be tricky-messy

Comment: Thank you nigel222. Unfortunately my file is 350M by today, and it will easily go to 500M next week.

Comment: A somewhat less brute-force way is to use re.split. I just tested splitting a 500Mb string into 500,000 strings and it took about two seconds on a cire-i3 PC with 8Gb.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a slightly less brute-force way  using `re.split()` I have tested the following takes mere seconds on a core-i3 with 8Gb RAM

```
huge="{" + "a"*1000 + "}\n"
huge = huge * 500000
len(huge)/1000000.0
# get 501.5 (Mbytes)
jsons =  re.split(r'\}\s*\{', huge)
len(s)
# get 500000, took about 2 seconds
del huge  # might be a good idea to free half a gigabyte asap.
```

split yields the individual JSON elements, each in its own string, minus open curly brace (except on the first) and close curly (except on the last). So the rest of the work (untested) would be

```
jsons[0] = jsons[0] + '}'
n = len(jsons)
jsons[n-1] = '{' + jsons[n-1]
for i in range( 1, n-1 ): jsons[i] = '{' + jsons[i] + '}'

# i'd anticipate another couple of seconds to get here

for j in jsons:
    data = json.load( j)
    # do whatever with data
    # will take as long as it's going to take ....
```